# Trouble converting a SQL Query to the equivalent LinqToEntities code?

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

**The short:**
A simpler way of summing up this question would be, can you apply a conditon on a join in linq?

I have the following sql query:

```
select cdm.cashID, cdm.DateTimeTillOpened, cdm.DateTimeTillClosed, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate
from CashDrawsMonies cdm
join Orders o on o.OrderDate >= cdm.DateTimeTillOpened
              AND o.OrderDate <= cdm.DateTimeTillClosed
join Users u on o.UserID = u.UserID
where u.UserID = 'C3763CC6-D1C5-4EF3-9B83-F7AB3BF8827A'
group by cdm.cashID, cdm.DateTimeTillOpened, cdm.DateTimeTillClosed, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate
order by o.OrderDate desc
```

***Alternative SQL@***

```
select *
from CashDrawsMonies cdm
where exists
(
    select * 
    from Orders o 
    join Users u on o.UserID = u.UserID
    where 
        o.OrderDate >= cdm.DateTimeTillOpened and 
        o.OrderDate <= cdm.DateTimeTillClosed and
        u.UserID = 'C3763CC6-D1C5-4EF3-9B83-F7AB3BF8827A'
)
```

I can convert most queries but on the join in Linq it always asks for an equal keyword and not something like >= or <= which allows me in sql to put a condition on the join. This is what makes me scratch my head as to how do I convert it then?

My linq-To-Entites model in code (c#) is set-up as:

```
Cache.Model.Orders
Cache.Model.CashDrawMonies
Cache.Model.Users
```

Appreciate the help.

***Attempt 1:***

```
                var results = from o in Cache.Model.Orders
                          from c in Cache.Model.CashDrawMoneys
                          join u in Cache.Model.Users on o.UserID equals u.UserID
                          where c.DateTimeTillOpened >= o.OrderDate
                          && c.DateTimeTillClosed <= o.OrderDate
                          select c;
```

***Attempt 2:***

```
            var results = from c in Cache.Model.CashDrawMoneys
                          from o in Cache.Model.Orders
                          where c.DateTimeTillOpened >= o.OrderDate
                          && c.DateTimeTillClosed <= o.OrderDate
                          group c by new { c.cashID, c.DateTimeTillOpened, c.DateTimeTillClosed, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.UserID } into temp
                          from t in temp
                          join u in Cache.Model.Users on t.UserID equals u.UserID
                          where t.UserID == selectedUser.UserID
                          select t;
```

Returns no results .... : S

***UPDATE:***

I re wrote my sql, the second peiece of sql does exactly what I want know. Just need someone to convert it for me somehow???

SQL Version 2 Converted Using Linqer:

```
from cdm in db.CashDrawMoneys
where
    (from o in db.Orders
    join u in db.Users on o.UserID equals u.UserID
    where
      o.OrderDate >= cdm.DateTimeTillOpened &&
      o.OrderDate <= cdm.DateTimeTillClosed &&
      u.UserID == new Guid("C3763CC6-D1C5-4EF3-9B83-F7AB3BF8827A")
    select new {
      o,
      u
    }).FirstOrDefault() != null
select new {
  cdm.UserID,
  cdm.DateTimeTillClosed,
  cdm.DateTimeTillOpened,
  cdm.LooseChange,
  cdm.Fivers,
  cdm.Tens,
  cdm.Twenties,
  cdm.Fifties,
  cdm.IsOpen,
  cdm.IsClosed,
  cdm.ClosingValue,
  cdm.OpeningValue,
  cdm.cashID
}
```

Compiles nbut produces the following error:

"The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joins on the first Attempt look about right. But did you turn around the comparison operator?

`where c.DateTimeTillOpened **>=** o.OrderDate`
`&& c.DateTimeTillClosed **<=** o.OrderDate`

**Update:**

You can't create a new object within LINQ2EF as it doesn't know how to translate that to sql.

```
u.UserID == new Guid("C3763CC6-D1C5-4EF3-9B83-F7AB3BF8827A")
```

You'll have to define the GUID before the linq statement and then use the variable

```
var gid = new Guid("C3763CC6-D1C5-4EF3-9B83-F7AB3BF8827A")

from cdm in db.CashDrawMoneys
where
    (from o in db.Orders
    join u in db.Users on o.UserID equals u.UserID
    where
    o.OrderDate >= cdm.DateTimeTillOpened &&
    o.OrderDate <= cdm.DateTimeTillClosed &&
    u.UserID == gid
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I managed to get:

```
                var results = from cdm in Cache.Model.CashDrawMoneys
                          where (from o in Cache.Model.Orders
                                join u in Cache.Model.Users on o.UserID equals u.UserID
                                where o.OrderDate >= cdm.DateTimeTillOpened && o.OrderDate <= cdm.DateTimeTillClosed &&
                                    u.UserID == selectedUser.UserID
                                select o).FirstOrDefault() != null
                          select cdm;
```

It's pretty close to what you got and did not have to worry about the guid as it was already created for me as I had a 'selectedUser' object.

The last line could be:

```
                                    select o).Any()
                          select cdm;
```

But I'm not fussed, I get the two variations but Im gonna stick with my first version.